# C++ copying chars from static to dynamic array adds a bunch of random elements

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I have an static array, but when copying values over to a dynamic array, I get a bunch of nonsense padded on. I need for the resulting dynamic array to be exactly 8 characters

```
unsigned char cipherText[9]; //Null terminated
cout<<cipherText<<endl;      //outputs = F,ÿi~█ó¡

unsigned char* bytes = new unsigned char[8];  //new dynamic array

//Loop copys each element from static to dynamic array.
for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
{       
    bytes[x] = cipherText[x];
}

cout<<bytes;     //output: F,ÿi~█ó¡²²²²½½½½½½½½ε■ε■
```

Comment: You didn't copy the null terminator to your dynamic array.  Make your dynamic array longer by 1 and copy the null terminator.  This is assuming that somewhere in the code that you have not shown you are actually putting a string in the cipherText that is null terminated.

Comment: If cipherText is null terminated, you aren't copying the null terminator.

Comment: if you're not initializing `cipherText`, then of course it's just going to contain random data.  Use `memset` or `bzero` or something to initialize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your code to copy the null terminator:

```
unsigned char* bytes = new unsigned char[9];  //new dynamic array

//Loop copys each element from static to dynamic array.
for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
{       
    bytes[x] = cipherText[x];
}

cout<<bytes;
```

This is assuming that `cipherText` does in fact contain a null terminated string.

Comment: Well now I feel stupid. For some reason I felt it unnecessary to copy over all 9 characters  i guess. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

C-strings need to be null-terminated if you want to properly print it. The machine has to know where to stop printing.

To solve this, make `bytes` one larger (9 instead of 8) to make space for the null character and then append it to the end:

```
bytes[8] = '\0';
```

Now `cout` will now to only read the first 8 character from the array, after that it encounters the `'\0'` and will stop.

Comment: Oh wow, didn't know that's how cout worked. It stops at null characters. Thanks!

Comment: @atsay714 that's how the `operator<<(ostream& , char const *)` works. Other overloads don't work that way

Answer (score 0):

How do you know cipherText is null terminated? Simply defining it won't make it null terminated.